# Softmax Derivative

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, softmax

I've been trying to build a neural network from scratch in python over the last few weeks. I've gotten it working with sigmoid, but trying to implement softmax has been killing me, entirely thanks to the softmax derivative.

I just don't understand how it works. Everywhere I look, people are using crazy math equations to explain it and everybody is just saying, "Oh, yes, that gibberish makes perfect sense!"

Well, it doesn't make sense to me. Could somebody please explain how the softmax derivative is supposed to work in plain English, with code examples (preferably in python) instead of math examples?

Comment: When asking 'please explain how the softmax derivative is supposed to work in plain English', do you understand why we would want to take the derivative of the softmax function (or sigmoid function for that matter)?

Comment: @Oxbowerce It allows us to whether we want to increase/decrease the weights/biases for a layer.

Comment: [This](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/) blog does a pretty good job explaining the Jacobian ( generalized derivative ) of the softmax function.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the programming part if you cannot grasp the underlying mathematical derivation of softmax.

Comment: I hope this blog helps you https://aimatters.wordpress.com/2019/06/17/the-softmax-function-derivative/